# Communicate slot with component dynamic to parent

Tags: vuejs2

I'm a little new in VueJS and communicate between components is heavy to understand without a Bus or Vuex.

I have 3 components: CompForm, CompField and CompText.

CompForm is a wrapper with  that cointain a lot of CompField. Here I have a data "form: {}".

CompField have a `<component :is...>` that call a component by a prop.

CompText is a component that is called by CompField

How I can pass the data of CompText to CompForm? I try with :value, @input, slot-scoped, emit and nothing works (Or I'm using it wrong). At this moment I can comunicate CompText to CompField, but I cant to CompField to CompForm.

I did a sandbox with that working:
https://codesandbox.io/s/n0yq3jyz7p

It's good that I'm doing? or is better that I use Vuex? Or other way?. Any suggestion is welcome :D

The idea es make a form with a lots of field type dynamic and create a form very easy way.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: _"How I can pass the data of CompText to CompForm?"_  you `$emit` an event which you will need to pass up the component hierarchy. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: Emitting an event from a **slot**: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4332 - a headache for a lot of people.

Comment: A really headache hahaha. I tried with $emit but parent don't receive nothing. I guess I gonna try Vuex